# why method inside oncreate event doesn't work?

Tags: android, methods

I have a **private** method like this

```
private void acaknomor() {
    List<Integer> generated = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (int i = 0; i <= 4; i++) {
        while (true) {
            Integer next = ran.nextInt(4 + 1) + 0;
            if (!generated.contains(next)) {
                generated.add(next);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    int[] arrayAcak = new int[generated.size()];
    for (int i = 0; i < generated.size(); i++) {
        arrayAcak[i] = generated.get(i);
    }
}
```

i call that method in `oncreate` and test by button click to show list value with a toast like this :

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    acaknomor();

    btn_next.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), String.valueOf(generated), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

The Question is why the toast show `null` when I put it inside a method , instead showing "**0,1,2,3,4**" ?

I tested my code without a method (put it raw inside **oncreate event** and it worked...)

Comment: can you post your log please?

Comment: Sorry I Make a SIMPLE mistake.....
I works now...

my mistake is i create a variable like this on top :
List<Integer> generated;

and in the method i create it again with the same name like this :
List<Integer> generated = new ArrayList<Integer>();

Thats why i have null value.. T.T

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your are declaring  `List<Integer> generated = new ArrayList<Integer>();` in side the method `acaknomor()`. So it is not visible for the Toast.

I suggest you to declare it at class level.

private List generated;

Now inside the the `acaknomor()`

```
private void acaknomor() {
    generated = new ArrayList<Integer>();           // Modify this line
    for (int i = 0; i <= 4; i++) {
    ...
```

Comment: @JiteshUpadhyay I appreciate. Do care to [Pay it forward](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). :)

Comment: @Kedarnath that is why i up voted(+1) the answers!! everyone should be appreciated who gives correct answer!!

Comment: @JiteshUpadhyay Yes you should do voting, but you do not need to comment after vote up. Let it be `Pay it formarward` , meaning just vote up and move on. No need to discuss about it.

Comment: oh yes you are correct!! i will make sure about the same!!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of this:

```
List<Integer> generated = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

Use

```
generated = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

And declare `List<Integer> generated` for your activity

Comment: thanks.. i realized it myself.. it was a blunder T.T

Answer (score 1):

please have a look at acaknomor method

```
private void acaknomor() {
    List<Integer> generated = new ArrayList<Integer>();....
```

use `generated = new ArrayList<Integer>();`

and make `List<Integer> generated =null;` Global which will help you on this issue

Comment: thanks.. i realized it myself.. it was a blunder T.T

Comment: no problem, it happens some times!! +1 for all as all seen the same answer to solve!!